# NSXMLParser, getting strange issue while parsing data from web service

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, parsing, xml-parsing

i am using Async method of calling web service from iPad App.

i receive correct data separated by '**' like

42**0031****New****2372–2398, NW Maynard Rd  Cary North Carolina United States**2372–2398, NW Maynard Rd

connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection  -- gives me correct data... then i do

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    if( m_xmlParser )
    {
        [m_xmlParser release];
    }

    m_xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: m_webData];
    [m_xmlParser setDelegate: self];
    [m_xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities: YES];
    [m_xmlParser parse];
}
```

after this below delegates get called

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
}
```

i checked string instead of "42**0031****New****2372–2398, NW Maynard Rd  Cary North Carolina United States**2372–2398, NW Maynard Rd" data 
what i receive is only "42**0031****New****2372" 1st called and foundCharacters gets called 2nd time which returns remaining string "–2398, NW Maynard Rd  Cary North Carolina United States**2372–2398, NW Maynard Rd"

but with rest records i get entire string, but with above data it gets break while parsing...

i did all sorts of testing, i am not getting why it gets only half string. 
only with this record.

Comment: Does all other records also have the ( - ) symbol ?

Comment: i debug with other result,   Bin Roll-In**    and  2372–2398 , any one can tel me character between two numbers......  is it from DB got saved....as character between Roll and In  is different then between 2372 and 2398,  because of which i guess i am getting strange issue..... let me know what kind of character it is..could not get on MAC..

Answer (score 0):

That method does not guarantee that you get the whole content. From [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSXMLParserDelegate/parser:foundCharacters:):

> The parser object may send the delegate several
>   parser:foundCharacters: messages to report the characters of an
>   element. Because string may be only part of the total character
>   content for the current element, you should append it to the current
>   accumulation of characters until the element changes.

Your best bet is to created a `NSMutableString` and keep appending to it until your delegate receives a `parser:didEndElement` call. You should start with the [XML parsing guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/Articles/HandlingElements.html).

Comment: i am not getting what type of character is there between 2372–2398  (character between both the numbers).  that character not present on MAC.... if i replace 2372–2398 with 2372-2398, it parses correctly...

Comment: Hm... your original text may contain an em dash (–) which is longer than an en dash (-). The en dash is what you get when hitting the key to the left of the equal key. Some text editors, particular MS Word, will convert en dash to em dash when it sits between word characters. Anyhow, do NOT assume that you will get all content in one call. You don't know what characters will trigger a split.

Comment: hmm but is there any way to fix it is web service itself.... C # if possible... as those results are coming from web service only.... kind of check and then replace ? but if i do individual web service then they are more then 100.... if i can get hint will be enough..

Comment: why i can think for web service fix...as App has so many modules..from code it is not possible...but can think from web service....

Comment: You can do a search and replace prior to parsing the XML in ObjC. But again, you are working on the wrong fix.

Comment: no no i do not want ObjC fix....if possible Webservice Fix only.... as thats point i am getting result from.... its kind origin ....

Comment: You can search and replace as you take in user input, or at the webservice before return data to the clients